# Filtrar lista a partir de strings semelhantes

Tags: angularjs, html5

Minha dúvida é como faço, utilizando o filter do angularjs, para filtrar itens de uma lista a partir de atributos string. Esses atributos são semelhantes, 'relevant' e 'non-relevant'.

```
<select class="select input" ng-model="classes">
    <option value="rel">relevant</option>
    <option value="non-rel">non-relevant</option>
 </select>
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:{classification:classes}">
...
```

O problema é que quando coloco no select "relevant", ele traz todos. Só consegue trazer especificamente se for o "non-relevant". Gostaria de saber se tem como eu retornar apenas os que só tem "relevant" ou só os que tem "non-relevant". Como eu poderia resolver esse problema? Agradeço a ajuda mais uma vez. Abraços.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `filter` aceita um terceiro parâmetro que basicamente obriga o valor a ser exato:

```
...
<tr ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:{classification:classes}:true">
...
```

Você pode conferir na documentação do [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).